# laser_scan position transformer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i create a laser_scan node which publish /scan topic, and i wnat to show it on rviz but i can't find position transformer and color transformer.
please what can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233060/laser_scan-position-transformer/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update**: If the measurements are outside the `LaserScan` message's reported min-max range, RViz won't visualize them.

In RViz, expand the Global Options dropdown menu (upper left) and set the Fixed Frame to your laser sensor's frame ID (the `frame_id` of your `LaserScan` messages).

This will allow you to visualize the laser scans without having to worry about the `map -> laser` transformation.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-27**:
can you explain more please? i am beginner on ROS

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-27**:
Have you succeeded in launching RViz? `rosrun rviz rviz`

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-27**:
yes and run laser scan with topic /scan but on rviz i dont found position transformer of laser scan

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-27**:
I don't understand what you mean by "i dont found position transformer of laser scan". Is that an error message? If not, maybe post a screenshot? Also, what's your 'Fixed Frame' in RViz? (see my answer above for how to find that)

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-27**:
fixed frame is /odom and i add laser_scan and odometry but i don't have laser_scan result in rvis
i hope that is clear

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-27**:
OK, cool. Now, in RViz, *change* the Fixed Frame from `/odom` to whatever your laser scanner's `frame_id` is. (That should let you visualize laser scans without any influence from the rest of the system.)

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-27**:
nothing also, this is a screenshot
[image: image description]

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-27**:
Cool, thanks. One last sanity check: `rostopic echo /scan` Are messages being published? Do they look reasonable? (frame_id, ranges, range_min, range_max) For example, if the measurements are outside the min-max range, RViz won't visualize them.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-28**:
yes the measurements are outside the min-max range

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-28**:
Then that's why RViz is ignoring them :-)

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-28**:
@jack, I've updated my answer above based on our discussion here in the comments. If it is correct, could you please "mark it as correct" using the checkmark button? It will help people who read this in the future.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-29**:
@spmaniato, i've uploaded my code. I have a problem of conversion from range to laser scan